# Error while crawling web python

Tags: python

when I try to run the code below this error was returned. I'd be much appreciated if someone can help to point out where I did wrong. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_crawler.py", line 26, in <module>
    links = get_all_links(page)
  File "web_crawler.py", line 14, in get_all_links
    url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
  File "web_crawler.py", line 2, in get_next_target
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"',start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"',start_quote+1)
    url = page[start_quote+1:end_quote]
    print(url)
    return url, end_quote

def get_all_links(page):
    links = []
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            links.append(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break
    return links

import requests
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon'
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.content
links = get_all_links(page)
```

Comment: For the difference between `r.content` and `r.text` (when `r` is a response object returned from `requests.get`), see the [documentation of requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Answer (score 3):

`response.content` is the raw contents of the request. They are not decoded it or anything, it's just the raw bytes.

What you want to use instead is the `response.text` attribute, which contains the decoded content as a string.

(You also probably want to use an html parsing library like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead of your current `page.find` approach)